# Identical li-ion packs in parallel

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, parallel

I'm looking for a 1kWh battery at 36V, something around 30Ah should be fine.

Browsing popular sites I see that the lower end starts at about $400 which is a bit over what I'd like to pay.

I stumbled into an assembled, BMS included, 36V 14Ah battery pack with unknown cells used and, of course, Chinese origin which only costs $100. I'm well aware it is likely crap, but hey I can always get my money back if it doesn't deliver what they claim.

Anyway what I was wondering is, if I order 2 of those, would it be possible to wire them up in parallel to get something close to 30Ah, given that both of them will have their own BMS?

Comment: `I'm well aware it is likely crap, but hey I can always get my money back if it doesn't deliver what they claim.` Funny but might not be likely to happen. Chinese suppliers are known to dispute what you dispute. The products they make _will_ meet your specs but the quality isn't that good, hence why one of the reasons the things they make are cheap (along with frequent currency adjustments). If you connect these battery packs in parallel, you'll get 36V and 28Ah.

Comment: (continued) `I'm looking for a 1kWh battery at 36V`, that'll give you 27A of current draw. So that means you'll be able to use your device for 1.037 hours... Definitely not worth spending $100 for each battery pack.

Comment: @KingDuken in my past experiences they always refunded me completely. I am genuinely concerned whether the BMS will cause complications when connected in parallel. Regarding your second comment I don't seem to catch your point, whether I buy this chinese version or a $400+ proper samsung or panasonic battery pack it will either way run for about an hour, theoretically that is. Sadly that's all I can afford and what I'll have to deal wit until battery prices go down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It should work fine to put them in parallel if we assume the BMS's on each are not doing anything out of the ordinary.

If you want to be extra cautious you could charge them separately.